# Terminal window stuck with the corner of another window drawn on it

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-terminal, 17.10

This is a weird one. Every time I open a terminal window the buttons at the top right corner are covered up by the corner of another window that doesn't exist. The problem persists even after a reboot! It's permanently drawn on there somehow.

The problem came about when I had both a VGA and HDMI cable plugged into the same monitor at the same time and it thought there was two monitors and behaved a bit weird. Anyway at some point it did this and now it's stuck like that.

Anyone know how I might go about fixing it without a reinstall?

This is what it looks like on every terminal window I open now:

[image]

---

**Update:** even after a fresh reinstall it's still there! I got a new SSD and started from scratch since the clone software only works with windows. There may have been another way to clone but I wanted to see if it would fix this problem. Maybe it's hardware related since it doesn't happen on any of my home machines.

**Update 2:** turning the "application menu" on in gnome tweaks removes the artefact but this is just a work around.

Comment: Fully power down the machine instead of doing a warm boot.

Comment: ok I think maybe I haven't done that and will try it. Can't do it right now though. I'll update when I do...

Comment: @psusi ok I tried a cold boot but it's still there.

Comment: Wow, that is really weird.

Comment: yeah I'm not expecting to solve it but you never know. someone might know what it is.

Comment: The same bugreport on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1724250.

Comment: @egmont thanks for the info! I thought it was just me but I couldn't figure out what I did.

Comment: @egmont if you post this as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: Well, unfortunately this is not an answer to your problem. I have no clue what' s going on. I'd appreciate if you could join the investigation in the Ubuntu bugreport and answer to my recent questions there.

Comment: it answers it in that it's a bug rather than something I did. I suppose without a fix it's going to remain broken. it's not that big of a deal to me, just annoying. if I get some time I will try and help with the bug report thing.